# PHP IF condition?

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

How would I better write an IF statement for this condition?

I have 4 variables to check wheather it's null or not.

`$pdf_locator21e, $pdf_locator21d, $pdf_locator21c, $pdf_locator21b`

1. IF `$pdf_locator21e` has values `{ $pdf_original = "forms\pdfForms\5pg.pdf"; }` IF it's NULL, then move to step 2
2. IF `$pdf_locator21d` has values `{ $pdf_original = "forms\pdfForms\4pg.pdf"; }` IF it's NULL, then move to step 3
3. IF `$pdf_locator21c` has values `{ $pdf_original = "forms\pdfForms\3pg.pdf"; }` IF it's NULL, then move to step 4
4. IF `$pdf_locator21b` has values `{ $pdf_original = "forms\pdfForms\2pg.pdf"; }` IF it's NULL

ELSE

`{ $pdf_original = "forms\pdfForms\CMS-485-487-1pg.pdf"; }`

I want to check is IF `$pdf_locator21`e has values first, then it will use `5pg.pdf` and STOP checking for `pdf_locator21d`, `pdf_locator21c`, and `pdf_locator21b`.

IF pdf_locator21e is NULL then it will check for pdf_locator21d, and so on..

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `if`, `elseif`, and `else`. Additionally the [`empty`](https://www.php.net/empty) function allows you to check is a variable is not empty (or not `null`). In the example below I'm using the `!` to do the opposite (i.e. if not empty). The reason I choose to use that instead of just `if($prd_locator21e)` is because if it's not set, that would result in `PHP Warning:` error messages because the variable isn't set.

You're looking for something along these lines:

```
if ( ! empty($pdf_locator21e) )
  $pdf_original = "forms\pdfForms\5pg.pdf";
elseif ( ! empty($pdf_locator21d) )
  $pdf_original = "forms\pdfForms\4pg.pdf";
elseif ( ! empty($pdf_locator21c) )
  $pdf_original = "forms\pdfForms\3pg.pdf";
elseif ( ! empty($pdf_locator21b) )
  $pdf_original = "forms\pdfForms\2pg.pdf";
else
  $pdf_original = "forms\pdfForms\CMS-485-487-1pg.pdf"
```

As pointed in the comments below, you could use [`isset`](https://www.php.net/isset) instead of `! empty` to check if a variable is set. The difference is that *it would allow* values like `FALSE` or `0` or an empty string which are considered to be empty.

For example:

```
if ( isset($pdf_locator21e) )
  $pdf_original = "forms\pdfForms\5pg.pdf";
```

Comment: Just as a side-note: keep in mind that `empty($x)` tests `false!==(bool)$x`, i.e. `$x='0'; echo empty($x) ? 'is empty':'not empty';` will print `is empty`.

Comment: @VolkerK - That's right and depending on the case `isset` may be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you use `if ... elseif....else`

so

```
if($pdf_locator21e){
      $pdf_original = "forms\pdfForms\5pg.pdf";
}elseif($pdf_locator21d){
       pdf_original = "forms\pdfForms\4pg.pdf"; 
...
}else{
    $pdf_original = "forms\pdfForms\CMS-485-487-1pg.pdf"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use **isset()** function for your task.

```
    if (isset($pdf_locator21e) && $pdf_locator21e != "")
      $pdf_original = "forms\pdfForms\5pg.pdf";
    else
      $pdf_original = "forms\pdfForms\CMS-485-487-1pg.pdf"

and so on....
```

Thanks.